# laravel Socialite Login with specific domain name (e.g abc.edu.pk)

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project where particular institute have own domain name (e.g someone@abc.edu.pk) i want to implement a login system using Laravel Socialite which basically perform this action. Only login with the specific domain(@abc.edu.pk) and restrict the user to login with above mention domain
I am done with laravel socialite login with google... how can i further change in my code to full fill my requirement...

my logincontroller.php

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
        $authUser=$this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        return redirect($this->redirectTo);
        //return $user->token;
}
public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
{
        $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
        if($authUser)
        {
            return $authUser;
        }
        return User::create([
            'name'=> $user->name,
            'email'=> $user->email,
            'provider'=> strtoupper($provider),
            'provider_id'=>$user->id
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check user using explode

```
$domain = explode("@", $user->email)[1];
if( $domain != 'abc.edu.pk'){
   reject login
}
//accept login
```